# StackExchange.Redis.RedisTimeoutException

Tags: c#, azure, model-view-controller, redis

I'm using version 1.2.6 of the package and often see the following exceptions in logs while connecting to Azure RedisCaches. Any ideas what may cause such errors?

> StackExchange.Redis.RedisTimeoutException: Timeout performing EXISTS controllers.usercontroller-getusersscroll-userIds=&userIds=&skip=0&take=2&status=Active, Inactive&orderBy=0&sortDirection=Desc:application/json; charset=utf-8:Bearer , inst: 0, mgr: Inactive, err: never, queue: 1769, qu: 1769, qs: 0, qc: 0, wr: 0, wq: 0, in: 0, ar: 0, clientName: <...>, serverEndpoint: Unspecified/<...>.redis.cache.windows.net:6380, keyHashSlot: 2692, IOCP: (Busy=0,Free=1000,Min=250,Max=1000), WORKER: (Busy=1,Free=32766,Min=250,Max=32767)

Comment: You are experiencing timeouts. Consider increasing your timeout values.